# Can not open port 6000 windows xp

Tags: windows, port, tcp

I am trying to connect to [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) using their software and can not. They told me the reason is *port 6000* is not open. I spent 3 hours on the phone today with ATT making sure the *6000 port* was open on their end. They said it was.

I have set the 2wire router to DMZ allowing all ports. I turned off the windows firewall, I turned off McAfee firewall and still can not connect. I tried in windows adding the port and added the port in the 2wire router that did not work. When running at the cmd prompt `netstat` **does not show the port 6000 being used**. Can someone help? I am lost.